# Toad script runner failed in running a procedure

Tags: oracle, toad

I've got a procedure which is inside a Package. It has one int input and one cursor output.

I right click the package and select 'Execute Packagers'.

Then, in the new window, I select the specific procedure and set the input parameter.

I clicked the 'Execute in Toad Script Runner', which builds a script:

```
Declare 
  --Declaration
  Var_P_APPLICATION_ID NUMBER;
  Var_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR
Begin
  --Initialization
  Var_P_APPLICATION_ID := 97

  --Call
  DB.MYPACKAGE.MYPROCEDURE (
    P_APPLICATION_ID => Var_P_APPLICATION_ID ,
    cur              => VAR_cur);

  --TRANSACTION  Control
  COMMIT

  -- Output values , do not modify
  :2  := var_CUR;
END;
```

When I try to run that script I get an error : "Expression is of  wrong type"
on the row that contains `:2  := var_CUR;`

Comment: No idea, I don't use *script runner*. However, if it generates the script *exactly* as you posted it, it is invalid (missing semicolons throughout the code) and won't run at all. Also, did you try to execute the procedure yourself, without the *script runner*?

Comment: how did you declare the variable that's to hold :2?

Comment: I tried to run the procedure by myself and it works just fine.                                     I declared the variable that holds :2 as REF CURSOR